# Analytic continuation of the incomplete beta function

Tags: beta-function, analytic-continuation

Is there a rigorous proof for the analytic continuation of the incomplete beta function $B(x;a,b)$ for all values of $a$ and $b$? The incomplete beta function normally restricts the values of $a,b$ as $a>0$, $b>0$. So I would like to extend these values to negative but I cannot find a good and comprehensive reference for this.

There is a given expression in wikipedia for the analytic continuation of beta function but I cannot see one for the incomplete one. By the way, the integral that I am working on is:

$$\rho=\frac{b_0}{1-q}\int_0^{1-(b_0/x)^{1-q}}v^{-1/2}(1-v)^{\frac{1}{q-1}-1}dv=\frac{b_0}{1-q}Beta(1-(b_0/x)^{1-q};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{q-1})$$

And I am working on $-\infty<q<1$. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the general complete description with the regularized Gauss hypergeometric function ${{_2}\tilde{F}_{1}}(a,b,c,x)$, see [1](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1Regularized/) and [2](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/02/02/0001/): $$
B_x(a,b)= \Gamma(a)\,x^a \;{{_2}\tilde{F}_{1}}(a,1-b,a+1,x), \qquad -a \notin \mathbb{N}
$$

When $a \le 0$ or $b \le 0$, the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) ${{_2}F_{1}}$ function can be used: If $a \neq 0$ is no negative integer, the result is ([3](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.26.0005.01))
$$
B_x(a,b)= \frac{x^a}{a}\,{{_2}F_{1}}(a,1-b,a+1,x), \qquad -a \notin \mathbb{N},
$$
else if $b \neq 0$ is no negative integer, then ([4](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.19.26.0007.01)):
$$
B_x(a,b)= B(a,b)- \frac{(1-x)^b x^a}{b}\;{{_2}F_{1}}(1,a+b,b+1,1-x), \qquad -b \notin \mathbb{N}.
$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I don't actually understand this. If the parameter $b$ takes a value of zero or any negative value, I can use the last equation? Is that right?

Comment: No, you can use it if $b \ne -1, -2, \dots$ otherwise $ c= b+1$ becomes zero, and the the Gauss function is undefined. The regularized function
$${{_2}\tilde{F}_{1}}(a,b,c,x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(c)} {{_2}F_{1}}(a,b,c,x)$$
can handle this because together with $\Gamma(c)$ you get a finite limit if $c$ approaches a negative integer or zero.

Comment: What i need is what works for negative values of b. I already tried in the mathematica, and it gave me the correct answer.

Comment: What i need is an extension of incomplete beta function that works for negative values of the parameter $b$. But i tried feeding up negative values of $b$ to the last equation and it gave me the right answers. Now I am confused since the last equation must only work for positive $b$'s.

Comment: No it **does** work for negative non-integer $b$. If $b$ is a negative integer and $a$ is not you can use the second formula, otherwise use the regularized function. But note the hint given at
http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/02/02/.
Using my own implementation I get for example $B_{0.5}(-1.5, -2.5)= 6.4$ (verified on Wolfram function evaluation).

Comment: I get it now. Thanks buddy

Comment: So for example I have $a=0.5$ and $b=-0.5$, I can use the last equation, right?

Comment: Yes, although if $a>0$  it is simpler to use the second formula, then you do not have to compute $B(a,b)$ and $(1-x)^b$

Comment: That's nice. Thanks.